# Activate MessageBox dialog of the C# Win Form

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, system-tray

I have a Tray app.

On clicking its tray-icon, it Show()s one form.
Then that form Show()s one MessageBox.

Then I'd click outside its window to make it lose Focus.

Now again, as it normally happens, when I click the form's window, the MessageBox blinks once & gets the focus.

What I want to do, is that if I click on the tray-icon, the MessageBox should again get the focus.

On the tray-icon click, doing the form.Activate() too wouldn't give focus to the MessageBox window! but activates the form window, keeping the MessageBox afloat defocused over the focused form window.

Can you help me implementing the behavior??

Thank you.

Comment: Does this help you? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18612/TopMost-MessageBox?msg=2068597

Comment: Try to use [overloaded version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx) of `MessageBox.Show` with `owner`, does it makes any difference?

Comment: Set `IWindow` for `MessageBox`

Comment: @Sinatr no specifying owner doesn't work either!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        notifyIcon.DoubleClick += delegate {
            form.Activate();
            form.Focus();
            MessageBox.Show(form, "text", "caption");
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        };
```

Comment: The MessageBox is already there, on click, I need to get that into focus!

Comment: If possible, call `Activate()` and `Focus()` before the message box is shown. If that is not possible, then you can try to find the `Handle` to the message box window, and then `SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCACTIVATE, (IntPtr) 1, (IntPtr) 0)`